Bartender Seagull - Multiple Serial Numbers In a Row - Breaking them up each into individual labels
I have a field of information from my data that is multiple serial numbers listed out in one row.
Is there a way to make Bartender break them up each into their own printed label?
They're written like FS09531' FS09532'
I have tried injecting a VB script in OnProcessData, OnPrintJobStart, and All Events, but I have 0 practical knowledge or skill in coding so I mainly relied on ChatGPT. This did not work for me. I also tried assigning the ' as a Field Separator when choosing the data source, but that also did not work for me.
More information: It's a calculated field from Epicor reports.
